# JSONRequest.get sample code

Tags: javascript, json, get

This is my first time using JSON and im a noobie in web development. On their website (http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html), they suggested using JSONRequest.get.
However, I keep getting the error "JSONRequest is not defined". My Code Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta Content-Type= application/jsonrequest >

<title>Insert Events Page</title>
</head>
<body> 

<h2>List of ALL events: </h2><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    JSONRequest.get("http://localhost:8888/mma/event/allevents", function(sn, response, exception){
            alert(exception || response);
    });
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some more information on what exactly you want to do. Furthermore you're far more likely to get quality answers to your questions, if you provide some code that you have tried already. This is not a place where people will build stuff for you, but rather improve the stuff you've tried already.

Answer (score 2):

you need to include the files that contains the JSONRequest object. I dont know if is the official site but can download from https://code.google.com/p/web-opm/source/browse/js/json/?name=client&r=f7c9a4447ed55570b0b056bbb90e82d310fb986f

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from the website you referenced:

Source: http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html

> Example:
>
> ```
> requestNumber = JSONRequest.get(
>     "https://json.penzance.org/request",
>     function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
>         if (value) {
>             processResponse(value);
>         } else {
>             processError(exception);
>         }
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> After JSONRequest.get has verified the parameters, it will queue the
>   request and return the request number. The done function value will be
>   invoked later when the outcome of the request is known.
>
> No cookies or implicit authentication information is sent with the GET
>   operation. Any authentication information must be placed in the url.
>
> The request may use either http or https. This choice is independent
>   of the security of the page.
>
> ```
> GET /request HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/jsonrequest
> Host: json.penzance.org
> ```
>
> After the server has acknowledged the request, it has until the
>   timeout interval expires to produce a response. If the time limit is
>   exceeded, or if the connection is closed before a complete response is
>   sent, then the request fails.
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/jsonrequest
> Content-Length: xxxx
> ```

Comment: how do you specify  "Content-Type: application/jsonrequest" in html? I tried <meta Content-Type= application/jsonrequest > but it did not work